# Error when exporting individual pages from ArcGIS DDP

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, error, arcgis-10.3, data-driven-pages

I'm working with a 52 page map book using data driven pages. I have used this before and haven't had any issues but I am currently getting an error message when I try and export individual pages. I can export the first initial page just fine, but then when I move to the second page and try to export that individually, it just goes into a cycle that doesn't seem to end in it actually exporting. Once I've closed the program, the error message that pops up reads "Exception thrown in destructor. Encountered an improper argument." I've never even seen this error message before and have no idea what it means.

I did talk to tech support about it and it seems to have something to do with the aerial basemap; once that is turned off things run much more smoothly. But I do need that imagery included in my maps and so far we don't have a fix.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and/or know of a possible fix?

Note: I'm using Desktop 10.3.

Comment: I've also encountered this problem with data driven pages in Desktop 10.3. I am initially able to export all the pages, however if I try and export a second time (exactly the same settings, data etc) it goes into the cycle and requires you to End Task in Task manager for it to stop. I haven't had this issue previously on 10.1 or 10.2. Any ideas would be much appreciated? Tom

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: I also encountered this error using 10.1. I had let some models run and the next morning the error popped up. I had never seen the error before this, and have not seen it since.