# How to Prevent Data Driven Pages From Hanging on Subsequent Export?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, arcgis-10.3, data-driven-pages

I am working in ArcMap 10.3.0 and exporting through Data Driven Pages (DDP).  The DDP export works as expected the first time and for immediate subsequent exports, but if I use DDP to export **again** after more than a minute or so (the time varies) from the same MXD, the program hangs and I have to shut it down through the Task Manager.

I can tell if it is going to hang up as soon as I click "Export" because the Export window does not show "Page x of x" text.  See screenshots here: https://geonet.esri.com/message/536459#536459.  Even if I let the computer run for awhile, the "Page x of x" text never appears and the export does not happen. This only happens on subsequent exports after more than a minute from an MXD.

This seems to happen whether I export a single page or the entire document the first time.  However if I resave the MXD with a new name and then export, it always hangs up and requires ArcMap to be restarted.  The problem seems to occur whether I am creating a new PDF file or overwriting an existing PDF file.

Other information:

- My map consists of an ESRI aerial basemap (no other raster layers), with five 10000' x 10000'  lidar contour shapefiles and about 10 other small vector shapefile layers.
- My export settings are: 300 dpi resolution & output image quality/resample ratio 1:2.
- I am working from a data server located in this building, but the connection speed varies.
- Another co-worker is having the same problems with the same MXDs on his machine.

**Edited to add this error message:** It appeared after ArcMap was hung up on a subsequent export, and hit "end task" in the Task Manager.  This is only the 2nd or 3rd time I've gotten this error message, but I thought it might be relevent.  (Also, I don't have an f:/ drive as shown in the error message.)

[image]

Someone else had this problem as asked on GeoNet here: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/161564
No solutions were presented to her question so I wanted to ask again here.

Is there any way to prevent ArcMap hanging up on a subsequent DDP export?

**Edited to add this code snippet,** which produces multiple exports without hanging:

```
import_path = r"R:\Projects\Project\GIS\MXDs\Project_property_maps.mxd"   # Path of .mxd
export_path = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\Test"   # Path of output file
field_name = "Project_INDEX.Pg_num" # Name of field used to sort DDP
pg_name = "Project_INDEX.Desc_" # Name of field used in PDF file name

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(import_path) 
for i in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
   mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = i
   row = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow
   print row.getValue(field_name)
   arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, export_path + row.getValue(pg_name) + ".pdf") 
del mxd
```

Comment: Have you seen similar from the print function. On 10.2 I had a problem where the print dialog would not activate correctly and then arcmap would hang similar to what you describe. Just wondering if they could be related.

Comment: Also, try exporting 1 page, and then doing it again with 1 page. see if that changes the results.

Comment: I have a similar problem with some MXDs but not most of them, and I haven't been able to figure out why only a few MXDs do it. In my case, Arcmap just crashes instead of hanging, so at least I don't have to wait to find out that it isn't working. The circumstances are the same: first export from DDP works fine, second time doesn't. Closing and reopening the MXD will allow me to export again.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any connection between filenames and the crashing for me. I'm working on a series of figures right now, about 20 MXDs which do have both periods and hyphens in both the MXD filename and the exported filenames. Most of them work fine but not all.

Comment: There may be something to that, I was just trying to reproduce the problem by exporting and then re-exporting immediately, and it worked fine.

Comment: my chat is blocked. Also try using the multiple pdf option. I have had a lot of trouble with adobe (larger files [>15mb] crash with out of memory). you might try repairing adobe install. Try exporting to eps, emf or png

Comment: are you creating a new pdf file each time? Try that also.

Comment: I can't duplicate here on 10.3.1 are you running the 10.3.1?

Comment: FWIW, I've experienced this problem with both 10.3.0 and 10.3.1

Comment: have a go at doing the export through the python window

Comment: Sara - what is the background or other data type you are using? -- I'm thinking high res **rasters** might be hanging things up when DDP switches to the next page. -- Try the export sans background (if that makes sense, i.e. most of your data is vector based and your background is a raster(s) of some sort).

Comment: With such a long comment trail on this question, I think you should **edit** your question to incorporate all the clarifications that you have provided so that it becomes easier for potential answerers to absorb those details.

Comment: Sara, have a look at the answer to [Exporting .jpg files from data driven pages in Arcmap](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25223/exporting-jpg-files-from-data-driven-pages-in-arcmap). You should be able to adapt this quite easily to help narrow down the problem. Also, to build on what @user23715 suggested, perhaps look at the resolution you're exporting the maps at, and try reducing it if it is quite high.

Comment: @PolyGeo I removed many of my comments and added them to the question above.  I can't remove other people's comments, so someone else may want to clean up the comments a bit now.

Comment: I just came across this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147673/error-when-exporting-individual-pages-from-arcgis-ddp which is dealing with a very similar issue.

Comment: @Adam I have been trying the Python and have not had it hang yet, so I'm hopeful that might be a workaround.  With that said, I cannot get my script to produce multiple pages; it is overwriting them all with the same file name.  Could you take a look at it?  I've copied my code into the question above.

Comment: Sara, you have your output path set with the complete file name: `export_path = r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\Test.pdf"`. This is what is causing your file to be overwritten. Remove the ".pdf" from that statement and add it to the export statement like this: `arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, export_path + row.getValue(pg_name) + ".jpg")`

Comment: replace ".jpg" in my comment above with ".pdf" sorry

Comment: @Adam Thanks.  I've been testing it with Python this morning and have not been able to duplicate the hanging problem.  Doing the DDP export in Python seems to be a usable workaround that solves my problem.  Can you please post it as an answer?

Comment: Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on comments from @Adam, I used a Python script to export my Data Driven Pages MXD with no problems with hanging on subsequent exports.  Using Python for the exports appears to have solved the problems I was having.

I used the following script which I added to an ArcMap Toolbox as a script.  (The script will only run through Toolbox, since there are parameters included.)

```
#Set Input Parameters
mxd = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) 
PDFpath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) 
PDFname = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

#Create an MXD object
mxd_doc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd) 

#Export to DDP 
ddp = mxd_doc.dataDrivenPages 
ddp.exportToPDF(PDFpath + r"\\" + PDFname + ".pdf", "ALL") 
del mxd, mxd_doc, PDFname, PDFpath
```

I would like to further modify my script to be able to specify which pages should be exported (instead of defaulting to "ALL") but this works sufficiently for what I need now.

Answer (score 3):

Since this has gotten only comments so far (including one of my own) I'll take a chance and figure the problem (if not some mystery of Windows OS) is caused by up to four interrelated things.

1. Your background raster(s) are very high resolution
2. Your export DPI is very large
3. Your Output Image Quality/Resample Ratio is set to 1:1
4. The location(s) of your data server(s) and/or connection speed is(are) causing a hiccup

Some combination of these is hanging your DDP export. And by "some combination" it could mean only one of them.

If I had to pick one I would look into the last one, especially if I were using an ESRI Online product or have extremely large data sets on a network or remote drive - even vector data and especially so if we're talking Shapefile (*just try using the Measure Tool when there are half a million vertices in your view*:).

Unfortunately this hang-up also seems to simultaneously corrupt the .mxd file. At root this seems to actually be a **Bug-in-ArcMap™** but I cannot find any indication that ESRI knows of or is doing something about this.

That leaves a labor intensive work-around of

- Saving your .mxd when you have something ready for publishing,
- Exporting one time (whether it be a single page, range of pages, or all pages),
- Then closing without saving,
- Then opening the .mxd again to repeat the 2nd and 3rd steps for each subsequent export.

*>EDIT*

Based on the recently linked question (*how did I miss that one?*) and ESRI being officially unaware - [see this PDF here](http://downloads.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/1031-IssuesAddressedList.pdf), I'd say it has something to do with the Basemap Service interacting with DDP (*especially if the pages rotate the data frame*). This problem seems to be unique to 10.3 and 10.3.1 and may not be resolvable without a formal fix.

Comment: 1) I am using an ArcMap Aerial basemap and no other raster images.  2) My export DPI is 300 which I would not consider very large (but maybe others would??) and 3) my resample ratio is 1:2.  4) I am working from a server in our building but have varying connection speeds.  It also uses a lock file system that can cause problems elsewhere.

Comment: This is a good summary of some potential hangups and the workaround is basically what I've been doing.  I'll do some more testing with removing large data sets and see if that seems to help.  Unfortunately those will be on my maps, so even if it is not a permanent solution at least it will help understand the problem.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling ArcGIS?

Comment: @ian I have not tried reinstalling it yet.  I may when I have time.  Another co-worker is having the same problems/errors with the same files.

Comment: @SaraBarnes oh I didn't realize that. Hmm. Have you contacted ESRI tech support?

Comment: @ian If I am not able to get any solutions here, I will end up contacting ESRI.

Comment: @user23715 Thanks for the edit.  I don't know how I missed that question either!  I do not have any rotation in my data frames, but am using an ArcMap Aerial Basemap.  I'll do some experimenting without it.

Comment: @SaraBarnes - If you find your own answer you can post it and take credit for it. Else edit your question. -- I don't often use DDP but I do help others who generate project atlases and such, so I'll be glad to hear what you find out. -- Though I won't be surprised if the answer is - "Install 10.3.2" :)

Comment: I am having this problem without using a basemap, so I am not completely sure it is tied to basemap service.

Comment: @otto - I expect it is tied to anything that slows down the drawing of the map as it cycles through its pages. -- ArcMap is famous for hiccups like this - same symptoms, different cause / same cause, different symptoms. Reboot, it works fine, Reboot and it stops working. Etc. To be fair to ESRI it is being run on a Windows OS (usually).

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue today.  I called ESRI support and came up with a workaround.  The issue is with exporting all data driven pages to PDF, geoprocessing results and scale dependent pages.

The workaround:

Instead of adding the imagery basemap thru the typical basemap button, I added a new ArcGIS server in ArcCatalog and connected to  http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/services and dragged the "World_Imagery" layer into my table of contents, then cleared my geoprocessing results and then removed the scale dependent option in data driven pages.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the scale dependent option" in Data Driven Pages?  I don't see that option.  I'm in 10.3.0.  Thanks.

Comment: In the extent tab in the data driven dialog make sure the radio button is set to "Best Fit" or "Center and maintain current scale", it should NOT BE SET TO "Data Driven Scale"

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you, but that is the option I used and I was still getting error messages.  I appreciate you posting though - this may be helpful to someone else in the future.