# Export all data driven pages to PDF using Python script

Tags: arcpy, data-driven-pages

I am a novice Python user but I am trying to create a script which will allow me to export all of the data driven pages within an mxd to a single pdf file (without having to open the mxd). I currently have the script below which works for exporting single pages. And the highlighted section was my initial (poor) attempt to export all pages based on what I have seen or read.

```
# Python script to run in windows.
# 1) Copy script into folder to run script
# 2) Edit quality and dpi variables if desired

import arcpy, os

# get current directory python script is in
cwd = os.getcwd()

# quality to export, BEST, BETTER, NORMAL, FASTER, FASTEST 
quality = "BEST"
# dots per inch resolution
dpi = "300"
res = int(dpi)

# Ask user to confirm settings and directory
print "Export ArcMap MXD(s) to PDF(s), " + quality + " Quality, " + dpi + "dpi to " + cwd + "?"

# pauses for user to press key to continue
os.system('pause')

# set folder path to current directory
folderPath = cwd

# prints message to console for user
print "IN PROGRESS...PLEASE WAIT..."

# counter to count number of PDFs
n = 0

# create fullpath from filename and folder path
for filename in os.listdir(folderPath):  
    fullpath = os.path.join(folderPath, filename)
# extract file extension
    if os.path.isfile(fullpath):  
        basename, extension = os.path.splitext(fullpath)  
        if extension.lower() == ".mxd":
# advance counter to count PDFs
            n = n + 1
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullpath)
# export tool with parameters
            arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, basename + '.pdf', resolution=res, image_quality=quality, colorspace="RGB", picture_symbol="VECTORIZE_BITMAP", layers_attributes="NONE")
            print basename + "...exported"

            del mxd

# prints message to console for user
nstr = str(n)
print nstr + " pdf(s) exported to " + folderPath
print "DONE"

# pauses for user to press key to continue
os.system('pause')
```

Comment: Please include code as text rather than as a picture so that it can be searched. There is a format button to make it look nice.

Answer (score 7):

I am a novice in Python as well, but I have a script that will do what it sounds like you are trying to do - export all pages of an MXD with Data Driven Pages to one PDF.

I run this through the toolbox in ArcCatalog or ArcMap.  The MXD you are running it on does not have to be open.

```
#Set Input Parameters
mxd = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) 
PDFpath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) 
PDFname = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

#Create an MXD object
mxd_doc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd) 

#Export to DDP 
ddp = mxd_doc.dataDrivenPages 
ddp.exportToPDF(PDFpath + r"\\" + PDFname + ".pdf", "ALL") 
del mxd, mxd_doc, PDFname, PDFpath
```

I developed this code based on my question here:
[How to Prevent Data Driven Pages From Hanging on Subsequent Export?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157187/how-to-prevent-data-driven-pages-from-hanging-on-subsequent-export)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! I think you are a few levels above me in terms of Python as I did not even write the script I copied above. What do I need to do to the script that you have provided? Do I combine it with my original script or just copy it in to the python window in the geoprocessing drop down menu? Sorry for my incompetence!

Comment: @HarryCatharell-Hargreaves To run the script, copy the text into a text file (notepad or something) and save it with a .py extension.  Then you can add it into ArcMap by doing this: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/adding-a-script-tool.htm

Comment: @HarryCatharell-Hargreaves If this answered your question, please mark it as "answered."  You can learn more here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: What would be data type for this parameters while setting in arctoolbox. `mxd = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) 
PDFpath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) 
PDFname = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)`

Comment: @GISDataButcher They should both be text strings.

Comment: @SaraBarnes I have successfully set your script up in Arc Catalog. Only thing is when I try to run it more than once, after updating a definition query to change the maps data driven pages will push out, it ignores the new query and prints out the same batch of maps as before. I added refreshactiveview() before the delete line but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

My code proposal :

```
import arcpy

# Set Input Parameters
mxd = r"C:\TEST\DATADRIVEN\Data.mxd"
PDFpath = r"C:\TEST\DATADRIVEN\Testing.pdf"
dpi = "200"
res = int(dpi)
quality = "BEST"

# Create an MXD object
mxd_doc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd)
mxd_doc.dataDrivenPages.exportToPDF(PDFpath, resolution=res, image_quality=quality, colorspace="RGB", picture_symbol="VECTORIZE_BITMAP", layers_attributes="NONE")
del mxd_doc
```